# How can I convert a *big.Int into a byte array in golang

Tags: arrays, go, go-ethereum, geth

Im trying to do calculations on a big int number and then convert the result to a byte array, but I cannot figure out how to do so this is where Im at so far. anyone got any ideas

```
sum := big.NewInt(0)

for _, num := range balances {
    sum = sum.Add(sum, num)
}

fmt.Println("total: ", sum)

phrase := []byte(sum)
phraseLen := len(phrase)
padNumber := 65 - phraseLen
```

Comment: [`Int.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bytes) method?

Comment: so im using this now ```phrase := sum.Bytes()``` which does seem to convert the number to bytes, but im having issues reversing the process to get the original number back.. the original numbers type on return is not important, any idea how i can retrieve it

Comment: [`Int.SetBytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetBytes) method. You really should start reading the docs.

Comment: Tried to read them thats why im here. still no luck with that but thanks anyway

Comment: @Kravitz: then please show what you've tried using the correct methods  as shown in the documentation. `Bytes` and `SetBytes` do what you've described.

Comment: got it sorted with sum.String()

Answer (score 12):

Try using [`Int.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bytes) to get the byte array representation and [`Int.SetBytes([]byte)`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetBytes) to set the value from a byte array. For example:

```
x := new(big.Int).SetInt64(123456)
fmt.Printf("OK: x=%s (bytes=%#v)\n", x, x.Bytes())
// OK: x=123456 (bytes=[]byte{0x1, 0xe2, 0x40})

y := new(big.Int).SetBytes(x.Bytes())
fmt.Printf("OK: y=%s (bytes=%#v)\n", y, y.Bytes())
// OK: y=123456 (bytes=[]byte{0x1, 0xe2, 0x40})
```

Note that the byte array value of big numbers is a compact machine representation and should not be mistaken for the string value, which can be retrieved by the usual `String()` method (or [`Text(int)`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Text) for different bases) and set from a string value by the [`SetString(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetString) method:

```
a := new(big.Int).SetInt64(42)
a.String() // => "42"

b, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("cafebabe", 16)
b.String() // => "3405691582"
b.Text(16) // => "cafebabe"
b.Bytes()  // => []byte{0xca, 0xfe, 0xba, 0xbe}
```

Comment: Note that this byte encoding does not include the sign, it only stores/sets the absolute value.